# Display seconds in a UILabel from a NSTimer which was selected from UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, nstimer

How can i display the number of seconds in a label from an NSTimer?

```
imageVC.h

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;

imageVC.m

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


        imageViewController *pickerView = [[imageViewController alloc] init];
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timeout)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
        }];

        }
    }
```

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: you want to show  your timer time on label right?

Comment: Yes correct also would you know how to link the UIPicker to the NStimer? Much Appreciated

Comment: yes, i think you want to pick time from picker right? or something else.

Comment: you can use date picker  with time mode for this to pick time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another timer with 1 second interval that updates the label

```
       -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
            {
                [super viewDidAppear:animated];


                    imageViewController *pickerView = [[imageViewController alloc] init];
                        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(timeout) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(setTimeToLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
- (void)setTimeToLabel
{
     counterPrivateVar += 1;
     self.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];
}
```

Comment: counterPrivateVar is throwing an exception.

Comment: i meant you need to decelerate a variable... int  counterPrivateVar in your h or m file -
@interface YourClassName : UIViewController

{

  int  counterPrivateVar   
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this set the timeOut value to max value you want.

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timeout) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void) timeout {
if (timeCount==0) {
    [timer invalidate];

} else {
    timeCount = timeCount-1;
    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timeCount];
       }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply timeCount throws an exception saying replace with TimeZone. so should i declare     int timeCount   in the interface

Comment: yes you can declare it as integer and set its value to max limit you want or you can change it if you want incremental count set time count to 0 initially and invalidate it when you reach max limit.